# Delete command after execwait is not working

Tags: nsis

I'm creating one installer. I need VC++2013 runtime for my applicaiton. So i'm checking and if not found VC++ runtime i'm installing it from my installer.
To do that, I'm copying VC++ runtime exe into programfiles/myapplication and running it using

```
ExecWait '"$INSTDIR\vc.exe" /passive /norestart' $0
Delete "$INSTDIR\vc.exe"
```

But the problem is vc.exe is not getting deleted. It remains in programfiles/myapplication folder.

I use `IfErrors` command and found that error occurs.
Please suggest me how to solve this

Comment: Do you have 3rd-party anti-virus installed on the problematic machine?

Comment: Yes, there is 3rd-party anti-virus installled in that machine

Answer (score 0):

`ExecWait` **always** waits until the child process ends but just because the process has ended does not mean you can delete the .EXE file. It should ideally mean that but in some cases Explorer or Anti-Virus will keep files locked for a couple of seconds. Without more information it is hard to say why it can't be deleted, [Process Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) will probably provide some clues.

You could try

```
ExecWait '"$INSTDIR\vc.exe" /passive /norestart' $0
Sleep 2500
Delete "$INSTDIR\vc.exe"
```

but since you are just going to delete it anyway, I would suggest extracting it somewhere else that NSIS will try to clean up for you instead:

```
Section
InitPluginsDir
File "/oname=$PLUGINSDIR\vc.exe" "c:\myredistfiles\vc.exe"
ExecWait '"$PLUGINSDIR\vc.exe" /passive /norestart' $0
SectionEnd
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I have already solved it using sleep. But using sleep does not seem very good solution. I was trying to find out actual root cause.
I will try the other approach you have seggested and let you know